# Laravel Many To Many Polymorphic Relation doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, many-to-many

hi I'm trying to use many to many polymorphic but somehow it doesnt work I attach my code can you find out what I do wrong?

my migration :

```
 Schema::create('stickers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('type');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('stickables', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('sticker_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('stickable_id');
        $table->string('stickable_type');
        $table->primary(['sticker_id', 'stickable_id', 'stickable_type']);

        $table->foreign('sticker_id')
            ->references('id')->on('stickers')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and my models

Trip model:

```
public function stickables()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Stickable::class, 'stickable');
}
```

Stickable model:

```
 public function trips()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Trip::class, 'stickable');
}
```

controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $trip = new Trip();
    $trip->name = $request->name;
    $trip->desc = $request->desc;
    $trip->creator_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $trip->save();

    $tags=$request->tags;
    $trip->stickables()->attach($tags);
    $trip->save();
    return redirect('/trip');
}
```

Comment: Could you specify what does not work? What is the result you expect and what is the result you get instead?

Comment: @Matey sure  I want to do something like this  `$trip->stickables()->get()` but I get nothing I looked at my database stickables table and sticker_id is always null

Comment: @MohammadrezA You can try using the sync method instead of the attach `$trip->stickables()->sync($tags)`

Comment: @Gadzhev yes i tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you should define your relationship:

`Trip` Model:

```
public function stickers()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Sticker::class, 'stickable');
}
```

`Sticker` Model:

```
public function trips()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Trip::class, 'stickable');
}
```

You don't need a model for your relationship (`Stickable`).You should create a model for stickers and define your relationship on that.

`Stickable` can refer to `Trip` or any other type of model you need to create a relationship with stickers. However in your code you have a `stickable` method on the `Trip` model, which does not make sense.

[Eloquent Many to Many Polymorphic Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)